# How to transfer skill from live agent chat request to custom field in case information?

Tags: custom-field, case, liveagent, chat

I have a task where I have to transfer the skill shown in the live agent chat request to a custom field in the case information that is generated once the live agent accepts the chat. See image below:

[image: Desired outcome]
My question is, when the live agent accepts the chat, where is the skill information kept, and how can I access it in order to populate the custom field in the case information section?

Comment: You might want to check the Live Agent rest API